# iOS fetching json object from json string

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
@"SaveRegistrationIDResult" : @"{\"Table\":[{\"Return_Code\":1,\"Return_Message\":\"ALREADY REGISTERED\"}]}"
```

I'm finding it impossible to fetch data from this json string.

I'm getting the table Table Object as a NSDictionary using this code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];          
NSData *processedJsondata = [jsonData objectForKey:@"SaveRegistrationIDResult"];
```

but I getting errors for everything i try ahead.

I'd like to fetch data from within the Table array ('Return_Code') and print it in a Log.

Comment: what error you got while trying above code ?

Comment: The first code block you've provided is not valid JSON. What is the value of the `data` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting json string so you can parse it like,

```
  id jsonString = @"{\"Table\":[{\"Return_Code\":1,\"Return_Message\":\"ALREADY REGISTERED\"}]}";  // or [yourDictionary objectForKey : @"SaveRegistrationIDResult"];

    NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Now you can get value of any key from above object like,

```
   NSArray *arr = [jsonObject objectForKey : @"Table"];

   NSLog(@"your result : %@", arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lion's comment worked.
This is how I fetched the value. Any optimizations welcome.

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSString *processedJsondata = [jsonData objectForKey:@"SaveRegistrationIDResult"];

        NSData *tableData = [processedJsondata dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSDictionary *tableJsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tableData options:0 error:nil];
        NSArray *tableArray = [tableJsonObject objectForKey:@"Table"];
        NSDictionary *tableObject = [tableArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *reposnseCode = [tableObject objectForKey:@"Return_Message"];


        NSLog(@"%@",reposnseCode);
```

Comment: I haven't commented! It is an answer : )